# Combinatorics problem about divisors

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There is a **combinatorics** problem that need some **Number Theory** background:

How many numbers there are such that is divisible by 30 and have exactly 30 divisors?

I need some idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Start with the prime factorization.  What do you need to have the number divisible by $30$?  What do you need for there to be exactly $30$ divisors?

Comment: Hint: there is a formula, for numbers written in form ${p_1}^{a_1}{p_2}^{a_2}...$ which states the number of divisors is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)...$. I think that's the tool needed for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$30$ can factorize : $30=2*3*5$
so the number with mentioned conditions should have prime factors with powers $1,2,4$. since $3$ prime factors are obviously $2,3,5$. there are $ 3!=6 $ such numbers.